# How does the ERAD device gain access to your personal bank account?

Tags: exploit, databases, privileged-account

I am trying to get specifics on how exactly this ERAD device is able to access and withdraw from personal bank accounts.

http://www.dailykos.com/stories/2016/6/8/1536190/-Oklahoma-has-started-using-device-that-can-take-money-out-of-your-bank-account-and-off-credit-cards?detail=facebook

I am pretty sure that the device does a direct query to FINCEN and is new technology provided via the Freedom Act, but I can find nothing on the www to prove or disprove this theory. Much less provide additional details.

How exactly can Ok PD lock a bank account in Ca via a device?

Comment: As @Desthro answered, they can't, because the article you linked to is simply wrong, either because the didn't bother to understand the technology or because they're lying about it.  These devices can only be used to determine the balances on prepaid cards, not credit limits on traditional credit cards, or balances of bank accounts.  If it isn't a prepaid card, these devices can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

In short, they aren't, and can't.

What they are probably doing is processing several electronic credit transactions. On a credit card, you can max it out (problem if the card doesn't have a hard-limit but has a soft-limit that you can go above and pay down to the soft-limit on your next bill,) and it'll prohibit further transactions, and since the funds are deposited into their account, it is akin to seizing those funds. On an ATM card, now, this is where it gets hairy, I am certain they are referring to "check cards" that have a Visa or Mastercard logo. So when they swipe it, they'll process multiple transactions against your bank account, and "seize" any funds. They likely process them in decreasing amounts of 2^n, starting at say $1000. If it works, you try again, if not, go to $500, then $250, then $125, etc. Even then, there ARE purchase limits on the card, so that may not be feasible for all users.

ATM Cards specifically are PIN-based only, and they can't coerce you to provide them with that piece of information.

OTOH, if a significant number of larger banks were "coerced" into providing this "service," and they receive a communication from one of these aforementioned devices with the appropriate information, they will oblige (read obey) and lock the targeted accounts out.

TL:DR it's either lots of E-transactions, or collusion between the government and your bank.

Comment: Also, it might be "secret regulation" similar to the Bank Secrecy Act.

Comment: I do not see any reference to a pin limitation.  I see it state a few times that is can access any card for any reason..   This is important because if they are correct, then you are not..   I don't think it's just a credit card swiper.  I think you are incorrect  http://www.news9.com/story/32168555/ohp-uses-new-device-to-seize-money-used-during-the-commission-of-a-crime

Comment: if it was just a credit card swiper, then you can just reverse the charges the next day and NONE of the complaints would be valid.

Comment: You can contest the charges, not reverse them, and it is at the institution's discretion upon investigation that determines whether those charges are reversed or not. Also, the fact that the funds are being processed by a third-party suggests that it is likely the case.

Comment: baloney.  my credit card will reverse just because I ask.  every card in my pocket is the same.  according to what I read, there ain't no reversing that device.  Everything I read says that the device 'must be' hitting a government IP in order to perform its job, in some way.

Comment: I worked in the banking/financial industry for 8 years, you can baloney all you like, but what I am telling you is true. They don't reverse it, they give you a temporary credit pending the investigation, and when they have concluded the investigation, they let you keep the credit or reverse it, letting the transaction stand. This is pretty standard stuff. That temporary credit is also at their discretion. Read your card agreement.

Comment: I also work with bank networks and an unauthorized charge/reversal is performed upon customer request. The only thing that will stop that reversal would be a flag from fiserv or a flag from fraud.   If the transaction can easily be reversed, then the device is complete junk and none of this makes any sense.  Plus, I still see no pin limitation but yet they are animate about 'any card'.

Comment: The third party ERAD may send transactions flagged that way then. I'm pretty certain there are cardprocessor APIs that would allow an authorized merchant (ERAD) to process transactions in that manner.

Comment: a flag from fiserv is a flag from Uncle Sam.  The 'only way' to get a packet on demand from fiserv is with big connections and congress. You would need something like a Freedom Act to get a packet from Uncle Sam, on demand, as a field cop.  Fraud would be internal to each credit card provider.  The device just sends a fraud flag to every single card carrier API???  Thats sounds pretty weak. I would love to find a doc  on that fraud api call (I have never seen one) That also still doesn't explain the pin limitation.

Comment: Apparently they can only hit prepaid debit cards, not other types of cards. Sources: [ERAD](https://www.erad-group.com/faqs), [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/instituteforjustice/2016/06/08/oklahoma-cops-can-now-seize-money-from-prepaid-debit-cards-without-filing-criminal-charges/), [Taylor Swift](https://twitter.com/SwiftOnSecurity/status/740733563209801728)

Comment: They're not doing any such thing.  As @MattNordhoff commented, they're simply reading the balances of prepaid cards.  They aren't doing anything with cards tied to bank accounts at all.